# Is it possible to compile/customize the .net framework/asp net from source code

Tags: asp.net, .net, mono

I recently discovered that Microsoft makes the .net frameworks source code open for the public and asp net stuff too.

Just wondering is it possible to compile/customize this and use it as a replacement for the official version?

What about compiling the .net for lets say mono/linux?

What about using the asp net source to compile it with mono?

Comment: Even if you can, *please* don't make your own custom version of the framework without an amazingly good reason. It's a bad idea for a staggeringly large number of reasons that I can't even begin to articulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ASP.NET webstack is open sourced and it can be customized as you want. Note, ASP.NET WebForms is not opensourced only WebAPI, MVC, SignalR and WebPages is open sourced. Also IIS is closed source the last I checked it.

.NET library is but just a bunch of codes and as with any code, it can be customized as necessary.

As with Mono, I am not very fond of the distant cousin of the original .NET. It feels clunky at best at the moment and keeps changing everyday. Its best to stick with Windows for .NET for now.

Comment: Adding associated links:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/